# php How to echo array data separately without using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have created the following function to return member data. However, I am getting an error when I am trying to return the data. Maybe, my method is wrong. What should be the correct way considering the following details?

```
function memberData(){
  global $pdo;

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id = :mem");
  $stmt-> bindValue(':mem', userId());
  $stmt-> execute();

  while($f = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $return[] = $f;
  }
  return $return;
}

$memData = memberData();
```

Doing `print_r($memData)` returns array of data as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [mem_name] => Shubham Jha
            [1] => Shubham Jha
            [mem_email] => shubhamjha1000@gmail.com
            [2] => shubhamjha1000@gmail.com
            [mem_phone_ext] => +91
            [3] => +91
            [mem_phone] => 9876543210
            [4] => 9876543210
            [mem_password] => $2y$10$x5LfvrM8VVH/Rzx9NlCW/uktETYufS8yH4VPN/mcwvpmlBJcbarDe
            [5] => $2y$10$x5LfvrM8VVH/Rzx9NlCW/uktETYufS8yH4VPN/mcwvpmlBJcbarDe
            [mem_phone_verified] => yes
            [6] => yes
            [mem_email_verified] => no
            [7] => no
            [mem_date] => 2020-11-16 08:33:22
            [8] => 2020-11-16 08:33:22
        )
)
```

How do I echo data separately? I tried using `echo $memData['mem_id'];` but that returned an error `Notice:  Undefined index: mem_id in E:\xampp\htdocs\market\includes\functions.php on line 157`

Comment: if your query returns only ONE Row then you dont need a loop to fetch that one row

Comment: Oh yes right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array from you function (unnecesarity in my opinion) but that will make `$memData` an array so use

```
echo $memdate[0]['mem_id'];
```

Alternatively as you are fetching a row on its key and therefore only one will be returned you could do

```
function memberData(){
    global $pdo;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id = :mem");
    $stmt-> bindValue(':mem', userId());
    $stmt-> execute();

    $f = $stmt->fetch();
    return $f;
}

$memData = memberData();

echo $memdata['mem_name'];    // for example
```

And it would be much better to inject the `$pdo` connection handle to the function rather than using `global` like

```
function memberData($pdo){

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id = :mem");
    $stmt-> bindValue(':mem', userId());
    $stmt-> execute();

    $f = $stmt->fetch();
    return $f;
}

$memData = memberData($pdo);

echo $memdata['mem_name'];    // for example
```

Comment: I will accept your answer... However, I do `global $pdo` method because when I do what you suggested it returns this error `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function memberData(), 0 passed in E:\xampp\htdocs\market\includes\functions.php on line 153 and exactly 1 expected in`

Comment: Thats I assume is because you didnt add the paramter to the function when you call it. `memberData($pdo);`

Comment: If I have to add it twice, better I write once with global :)

Comment: Actually the dangers of using global variables far outweighs the requirement to pass things as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Becase your have an array, and a array it's a collection of another array's or object, so you need to do `echo $memData[0]['mem_id']` as example of your code.

I strongly suggest to you study primordial programming and basic of the objects in programming (this is not related to programming in PHP, but general programming).

And please, read the [documentation](https://php.net), if you get 1 hour everyday to read the documentation it'll be good for you, with a simple search you can found anything you want to learn.

As to discorver you problem if you [ever have read this artice in the official php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) you'll gonna avoid this kind of errors and problems in the future.